# wpf Listview with buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, button, binding

I have a listview with buttons for each row, but when I bind the IsEnabled property to the SelectedIndex still keep enable all the buttons, I just need this one, and also I have another button that has to be enable depends on the property of the object in the listview.

e.g I have a class File that has a property bool HasLckFile, and I need that the download button keep disable until the user upload, but the binding is not working.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" Style="{StaticResource CustomListViewStyle}" Margin="470,0,0,0" SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Filename}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Filename}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="download" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="btnDownload">
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="upload" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="btnUpload">
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Why not bind Button.IsEnabled to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}` just as you did with the checkbox?

Comment: I do not understand your logic/intent. It seems (based on your code above) that you want to enable *all* buttons if *any* item is selected. However, it should be more sensible to enable only the one button of the selected item (as Ed Plunkett suggested).

Comment: Personally I can't see any sense in ever disabling any of them based on row selection. Why require the user to select the row first? It's unnecessary.

Comment: You've got a problem with your Filename column. You don't want a column within a column. This is all you want: `<GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Filename}" />`

Comment: not working even with the IsEnable property

Comment: @YaraUndomiel It works perfectly if you do as I said. I have tested it with your code. Please show me what you tried.

Comment: ok, i want to enable one button, I have 2 buttons only one should be enabled and the other depends on the property of the selecteditem

Comment: I don't know what that means, sorry. I told you how to make a button be enabled only when its row is selected. Now, please answer my question and show me what you tried.

Comment: I've got a listview with two files, 1 has a lock file and the other don't, when I select the one that has the lock file the download button can't be enabled, is has to be disabled, the other button as soon you select the item becomes enable, that is working but not the download button

Comment: Please show code for the problem you still have.

Comment: The row item class displayed in the ListView should have a boolean property indicating whether the file has the lock file. It should properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged. You can then bind that property: `<Button IsEnabled="{Binding HasLockFile}" ... />`. `HasLockFile` should be a property of the same class that has the `Filename` property you are binding in the second column.

Comment: thanks, that what I need it. thanks, Ed Plunkett